# INNER JOIN and GROUP BY to prevent duplicate results

Tags: mysql, orm, group-by

### Context:

I'm working on a simple ORM (for PHP) that automatize most of queries, based on a static configuration.

Thus, from tables and entities definitions, the library handles joins automatically and generates appropriate fields/table alias... No problem for LEFT joins but INNER may result in duplicated results in case of relation One-to-Many.
My thought was to automatically add a GROUP BY clause (on the auto-increment key) if necessary.

### The question

Is it correct to consider that I need to add a GROUP BY clause if (and only if) the join's ON and WHERE conditions doesn't match a unique key of the joined table ?

### Example

A very simple example, where I want to select all events with (at least) an associated Showing.
*If there is an other way to do it without INNER JOIN, I'm interested to know how :)*

```
CREATE TABLE `Event` (
    `Id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `Name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `Event` (`Name`) VALUES ('My cool event');

CREATE TABLE `Showing` (
    `Id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `EventId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `Place` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (`EventId`) REFERENCES `Event`(`Id`),
    UNIQUE (`EventId`, `Place`)
);
INSERT INTO `Showing` (`EventId`, `Place`) VALUES (1, 'School');
INSERT INTO `Showing` (`EventId`, `Place`) VALUES (1, 'Park');



-- Correct queries
SELECT t.* FROM `Event` t INNER JOIN `Showing` t1 ON t.Id=t1.`EventId` WHERE t1.`PlaceId` = 'School';
SELECT t.* FROM `Event` t INNER JOIN `Showing` t1 ON t.Id=t1.`EventId` AND t1.`PlaceId` = 'School';


-- Query leading to duplicate values
SELECT t.* FROM `Event` t INNER JOIN `Showing` t1 ON t.Id=t1.`EventId`;


-- Group by query to prevent duplicate values
SELECT t.* FROM `Event` t INNER JOIN `Showing` t1 ON t.Id=t1.`EventId` GROUP BY t.`Id`;
```

Thanks !

Comment: dont do that, use composer and download a simple orm already available

Comment: That's not the point, I won't discuss why I want to create my own ORM, maybe it's for fun, maybe it's for learning purpose, maybe it is by challenge or just stupidity... no matter what, you give me no understanding by not answering my question :)

Comment: instead of `group by`, why don't you use `select distinct`? Also, consider what the user needs: If the user is querying tables with a one-to-many relation, they may be willing to accept (or even may need) the duplicate rows.

Comment: Thanks for the distinct trick, it works well !

Comment: Regarding the needs, it only concerns myself in a very first time. My main goal is not proposing what other ORMs do (dynamic would be right), but trying to automatize most common queries only from static table/entities definitions ! Simple queries, joined fields, counts, link tables... for more complex work, write by hand the query or use a "professional" ORM :)

Answer (score 2):

(this should be a comment but its a bit long)

> No problem for LEFT joins but INNER may result in duplicated results in case of relation One-to-Many

It's clear from that sentence that at least one of us is very confused about how a relational database works, and how object-relation mapping should work.

> Query leading to duplicate values

The rows produced are not duplicates - you've written the query so it doesn't show you why they are different:

```
SELECT t1.place, t.* 
FROM Event 
INNER JOIN Showing 
ON Event.Id=Showing.EventId;
```

If you're not interested in the data from 'showing' then why is it in your query? If you have events without related showing records then you should be using an 'EXISTS' - not a join (consider where you have a single event but 3 million showings)

```
SELECT t1.place, t.* 
FROM `Event` t 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
  FROM Showing
  WHERE Event.Id=Showing.EventId);
```

If you are strictly implementing ORM, then you probably shouldn't be writing queries with joins at all - but IMHO, the scenario is better served by using factories.

Comment: Perfect ! EXISTS was what exactly I need in this case :)

Comment: However, I was not claiming that the result was unexpected but only that's not the result needed, since I'm making an ORM, it implies that results must be converted into unique entities. Joins are sometimes useful, for example if I need to get some "readonly" infos from another table like the entity's parent name, count of children, etc.

Comment: Without link to this example (for which EXISTS is the best solution) : in the scenario I need to get some informations from the foreign table, i'll then use a join. What about my original question concerning GROUP BY and UNIQUE constraint relationship ? Can I consider a request as secure (= will return only one result), from the moment all fields defined as unique constraint are compared to constant values in ON/WHERE clauses ?

Answer (score 0):

The data is saying that "My Cool Event" is happening at the park, and at the school. If you inner join the tables you will get more than one result.

Do this query to see what is going on:

```
Select t.*, t1.* FROM `Event` t INNER JOIN `Showing` t1 ON t.Id=t1.`EventId`;
```

That is the same query as your duplicate query, but selecting columns from both tables.

The first line of results says the event is happening at the park. The second line says that the same event is happening at the school.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would do if I needed data from the second table. But as symbacbean mentioned, using WHERE EXISTS is far better than using a join in the opposite case. Anyway, thanks for the clarification :)